# Cannot get property of the object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have following code:

```
     var userId = r.response[0].uid; 
     if (typeof ratings[userId] !== 'undefined'){
        ratings[userId].likes = ratings[userId].likes++;
        ratings[userId].name = r.response[0].first_name +" "+ r.response[0].last_name;
     } else {
        ratings[userId] = new Object;
        ratings[userId].likes = 1;                          
        ratings[userId].name = r.response[0].first_name +" "+ r.response[0].last_name; 
     }
```

So i Have strange thing. When I use console.log(ratings) to see what is in object, it shows me all properties of this object. But when I try to get any property like this:

```
 console.log(ratings[12345]) or console.log(ratings["12345"])
```

it is undefined. But `console.log(ratings)` said me that I have property 12345 (it is an object too).
What is wrong in my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: If it is an object, are you sure you shouldn't be referencing it like `ratings["12345"]`? Just a guess, this is not my strong suit.

Comment: It should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/KNjfw/. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo with the exact data you have (at least the property names). Are you sure that there isn't a space before or after the digits in the property name (or any other hidden character)?

Comment: No, ratings['12345'] has the same effect - it`s undefined.

Comment: Well, there isn't a problem in the way you add a `userId` to `ratings`; http://jsfiddle.net/FfQyu/1/. Seems to be something to do with the values you have in `r.response[0]`. Also, `ratings[userId].likes = ratings[userId].likes++` should either only be `ratings[userId].likes++;` or `ratings[userId].likes += 1;`.

Comment: Yes, if I put `var foo = {12345: 'bar'};` in my code in the same place, where I`ve declared `ratings`, and use `console.log(foo[12345]);` it works correct. My

Comment: ... it works correct. `results` is an object with the structure like this: http://d.pr/i/pY0Z

Comment: `results`? Do you mean `ratings`? Do you have a link to your page? I don't we canot do more for you otherwise. If the property is really the string/number `12345`, it will work fine. So it seems this not case... check that.

Comment: I have no page but here my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Jd6nh/ I've deleted some unimportant fragments. In my opinion, problem could be in variable scope.

Comment: The code is not useful if it cannot be executed. The problem is likely to be with the data you get, not your code.

Comment: @Felix Kling No, data is correct. Into `VK.Api.call` function all works ok, but if I try to use it beyond the function, it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/qn3PW/ I've marked places in the code, where it works and where not (lines 36 and 38).

Comment: Oh, now I get it. The problem is that you are trying to access the data before it was populated. `VK.Api.call` is probably *asynchronous*, i.e. the callback you provide is executed some time in the future, *after* the `console.log` call in line 38. You have to put or call all code that has to deal with `ratings` inside the callback.

Comment: @Felix Kling looks like you're right. And can I bind any callback for other callback? I have to do something only after second `for`-loop on the line 17 finished his work and I have all requested data.

Answer (score -1):

If you use numbers as ID for the users, then you have to use

```
var userId = '12345';
ratings[userId];
```

or

```
ratings['12345'];
```

or

```
ratings[12345+""]; // this is the last resort, if possibile don't use it!
```

Keep in mind that pure numbers aren't allowed as JavaScript variable/keys identificator, but if they are coerced to string, then you can use them as key in objects.

Comment: `ratings[12345]` is perfectly valid to use. Every property name is a string internally, so numbers are *automatically* coerced to strings (like any other data type btw).

Comment: you're right @FelixKling. I never used this form because ambiguous and error prone.